# EOF exception in hadoop eclipse/ setting up hadoop in eclipse

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, hadoop, mapreduce

```
 softwares description : eclipse Juno version latest
 hadoop : 1.0.4
 hadoop eclipse plugin : 1.0.4 (created through apache ant)
```

I am trying to set up a new location of hadoop in eclipse but this give me error as

"`Call to localhost/127.0.0.1:54310 failed on local exception:java.io.EOFexception`".

I have searched on net but couldn't resolve the problem. I have also checked my netstat status and is given as follows

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address Foreign Address State 
tcp 0 0 localhost:39839 localhost:54311 ESTABLISHED
tcp 0 0 localhost:59944 localhost:54310 ESTABLISHED
tcp 0 0 localhost:60140 localhost:54310 TIME_WAIT 
tcp 0 0 ubuntu-2.local:46841 channel-ecmp-05-a:https ESTABLISHED
tcp 179 0 localhost:54311 localhost:40006 ESTABLISHED
tcp 0 0 localhost:60141 localhost:54310 TIME_WAIT 
tcp 0 0 localhost:60146 localhost:54310 ESTABLISHED
tcp 180 0 localhost:54311 localhost:40000 CLOSE_WAIT
```

It seems that eclipse tries to make a connection but after some time due to zero byte return close the connection. Why I am getting this error ? Is there any issue with proxy server or firewall. Please help me out.

Comment: What ports are your name node and job tracker listening on (`netstat -atn | grep LISTEN`) - which port does 54310 relate to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was having the same problem.The eclipse plugin you have created from ant will not work in this case may be because it overwrites some hadoop configuration (check buid.xml for more details)  It is mainly due to the hadoop eclipse version not matching with your hadoop installation. You can install hadoop-0.20.1 available from [here](http://archives.apache.org) and hadoop eclipse plugin from [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MAPREDUCE-1262) and give it a try. It will work. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you can include `hdfs-site.xml` under src of your project it should solve your problem. And if you are using Hbase then include `hbase-site.xml` too